# Cannot connect to EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an ec2 instance running an express app and I am unable to hit the URL and reach the server. I think it might be because my server is not in the base directory. I am new to this dev ops thing.

I am running my server.js file in a custom /server directory so /server/server.js

I am trying to hit the URL below

```
http://ec2-44-***-18-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001
```

I get back **"This site can’t be reached"**

I tried

```
http://ec2-44-***-18-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/server
```

I get back **"This site can’t be reached"**

Wondering why I cannot hit this?

UPDATE:

I followed this to a 'T' and still no change?

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-attach-igw-vpc/

UPDATE 2:

So I found the issue. The node server on reboot does not auto start. I have forever but it does not get run on reboot. So I need to input user data (bash file) to start the server. I cannot seem to get the path to forever or my server.js correct in the bash file?

If I ask

```
"which forever"
~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/forever
```

My server code is at

```
/home/ec2-user/server/server.js
```

So I tried this in my user data text

```
#!/bin/bash
~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log /home/ec2-user/server/server.js
```

I rebooted and the bash script does not work as my server is not started. I have to go to the command line and run this from my `~/server directory (on ec2 this is /home/ec2-user/server)`.

```
forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log server.js
```

Comment: Is there any webserver (apache, nginx, etc) running along with this app? Is that correctly bind to your app?

Comment: If you access `https://localhost:3001` from the command-line on the EC2 server itself, does it work? (eg, try it with curl)

Comment: Not running it on localhost. This is all on amazon. Going to edit this as I found the issue. I know how to resolve but cannot get paths right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your security group in aws to allow inbound requests from any (0.0.0.0/0) networks on the port where your node app is running

Comment: I did that. Its Custom TCP - TCP - Port 3001